# Routing ASP.NET MVC root application to MVC virtual directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, directory, routes, virtual

I have an MVC application setup as a root application. With in that root dir I have a virtual directory that is also an MVC app. I need to navigate from the root app to the virtual directory. The first hurdle was finding the controller that existed in another namespace, and I was able to do that as follows..

```
    Dim namespaceControllers() As String = {"ExternalAssemblyName"}

    routes.MapRoute( _
        "virtualroute", _
        "ExternalAssemblyName/{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "testvir", .action = "Index", .id = ""}, _
        namespaceControllers _
    )

    routes.MapRoute( _
        "Default", _
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = ""} _
    )
```

It correctly finds the controller, however it still tried to locate the view in the root application, not the virtual dir. If I move the View from the virtual dir to the root dir, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Routes can be tricky.  I can't recommend a fix without seeing your application (someone with more experience might be able to), but I can suggest installing the [RouteDebugger tool](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx) to help with routing issues.  It has helped me work out routing issues multiple times.

It's also available as a NuGet package.